# Make jQuery slider change div properties

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twentytwenty

I'm kind of new to this and I'm using [ZURB's twentytwenty plugin](https://github.com/zurb/twentytwenty). I got it working and everything, but I want the slider to change my `.hero` properties ( from `display: block;` to `display: none;` ) to make `.hero2` appear instead when the slider is taken all the way to the right, and `.hero3` appear when taken all the way to the left.

I think I need to use or call upon the `var minMaxNumber` or the  `var sliderPercentage` from the `jquery.twentytwenty.js` file:

```
  var minMaxNumber = function(num, min, max) {
    return Math.max(min, Math.min(max, num));
  };


   var getSliderPercentage = function(positionX, positionY) {
    var sliderPercentage = (sliderOrientation === 'vertical') ?
      (positionY-offsetY)/imgHeight :
      (positionX-offsetX)/imgWidth;

    return minMaxNumber(sliderPercentage, 0, 1);
  };
```

Comment: I recommend not changing the source file. Maybe look at the css classes of active/ non active items and force a display block

Comment: How would I do this?